# what is mean black & white texture

Tags: uv

I download .obj modeling file on the internet
I open the 'texture' file there is a lot of black and white image.
I think black is mean that a part of a model.
Can I select only the black part of UV map or model?
I want to put on a material to the black part.

Thanks!

Comment: Add some pictures it will be easy to help.

Answer (score 1):

The map could be a roughness map, metallic, Transmission, and so.
GrayScales give you a value for drive a single parameter.

Can you post images?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/3jQejmu

Comment: yes! it's a value channel.

This map could be controlling values like roughness, metallic, transparency, SSS.

The map can't be Diffuse, because is using values like zero and one.

Comment: How can I use value channel? Should use node? Can you show me an example? Really thanks

Comment: Please post model printScreens and the "demo" result.